# BigInteger ModInverse

Tags: .net, vb.net, biginteger, dsa

Is this VB calculation

```
Dim s As BigInteger = (BigInteger.ModPow(k,q - 2,q) * (m + x * r)) Mod q
```

a proper implementation of this written calculation

[image]

I'm basing my calculation of the fact that

[image]

can be computed by

[image]

as per [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) on Digital Signature Algorithm

Comment: What did you get when you tried a few sample case?

Comment: It's the special case, when q is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this equation is correct.